# Why are my 'if' and 'else if' statements not working?

Tags: c++

My question is to both:
Allow the user to enter a name and get custom messages based upon the name entered, and, when you collect the name from the user, convert the collected name to lowercase.

Thus, in my 'void test_user_details()' function, I made a custom message if the user puts in either Tim or John, but when I test the code it doesnt work? It skips the custom message. Also, I used "to_lowercase(name)" but the output isnt lowercase, it stays the same.

It seems like my if and else if functions arnt running at all and I dont know why.

Here is the full code of the program:

```
#include "splashkit.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string read_string(string prompt)
{
    string result;
    write(prompt);
    result=read_line();
    return result;
}

int read_integer(string prompt)
{
    string line;
    line = read_string(prompt);
    return convert_to_integer(line);
}

 ***************
void test_user_details()
{
    string name;
    string line;
    int age;

    name = read_string("What is your name: ");
    line = read_string("What is your age: ");
    age = convert_to_integer(line);

    write_line("Hello, " + name);

    if (to_lowercase(name) == "Tim")
    {
        write_line("\nWelcome Tim, creator of this program");
    }

    else if (to_lowercase(name) == "John")
    {
        write_line("\nWelcome John, tester of this program");
    }

    else
    {
        write_line("Are you Tim or John?");
    }

    write("Age: ");
    write_line(age);
}


void play_game()
{
    string line;
    int guess;
    int target;

    target = rnd(100) + 1;

    write_line("Guess a number between 1 and 100 (inclusive)");

    while(guess != target)
    {
        write("Enter guess: ");
        line = read_line();

        guess = convert_to_integer(line);

        if (guess < target)
        {
            write_line("Sorry, the number is greater than " +         
            to_string(guess));
        }
        else if (guess > target)
        {
            write_line("No, the number is less than " + 
            to_string(guess));
        }
    }

    write_line("You guessed correctly! The number was " + 
    to_string(target));
  }

 int main()
 {
    string line;
    int option;

    do
    {
        write_line("1. Play Game");
        write_line("2. Quit");

        write("Choosen option: ");
        line = read_line();
        option = convert_to_integer(line);

            switch(option) //switch function
            {
            case 1:
                test_user_details();
                play_game();
                break;
        
            case 2:
                write_line("Game ends.");
                break;

            default:
                write_line("Please enter an option from the menu");
            }
    } while (option!= 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you convert the string to lower case and then compare it to a string which has an upper case character in it, the result is obviously always going to be `false`. Make the string you are comparing to lower case as well: `if (to_lowercase(name) == "tim")` - note `tim` not `Tim`.

Answer (score 2):

assuming your `to_lowercase` returns a string in lower case it will never match:
`"Tim"` or `"John"`